# JPA Hibernate. Persist parent and children entities with foreign key reference to a parent in one call

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following problem: Having a class A

```
 Class A {
      ...

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
      @JsonIgnore
      private Long id;

      @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JsonView(View.Extended.class )
      @JoinColumn(name="b_fkey", referencedColumnName = "id")
      List<B> b;
      ...
 }
```

and class B:

```
 Class B {
      ...
      private Long b_fkey;
      ...
 }
```

I am trying to persist it as follows:

```
 ...
 A a = new A();
 a.setStuff();
 A aa = aDao.save(a);
 // no list of B's

 for(B b : List<B>) {
     b.setB_fkey(aa.getId());
     bDao.persist(b);
 }
 ...
```

This works perfectly, but I want it to be saved in the following X-way:

```
 ...
 A a = new A();
 a.setStuff();
 a.setB(List<B>)
 aDao.persist(a);
 ...
```

now it throws an error "Column 'f_key' cannot be null", because f_key is a foreign key which is referencing not yet generated value of a.id.

Question: how to save it in the "X way"?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have two problems:

First, you are mapping a bidirectional relationship but only "half-hearted", i.e. you are not mapping A into B, only its ID.

Better map like:

```
Class B {

  @ManyToOne(...)
  private A a;
}
```

Second, if you are mapping a bidirectional relationship in Hibernate, you MUST set both sides (see https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/).

This is mostly done by having a method like:

```
Class A {
   void setB(List<B> bs) {
     this.bs = bs;
     for (B b: bs) {
         b.setA(this);
     }
   }
}
```

If you do not need A in B, you can also go for a unidirectional mapping.

Comment: I don't need A in B. That's correct, so I don't need to define ManyToOne in Class B. I need only OneToMany in A, also in A 
  
     public void setB(List<B> b_list) {
  // undirectional mapping
  for(B b : b_list)
   b.setF_key(this.getId());
  this.b = b;
 }

this would not work, because id in still null when the function is called

Comment: B as you describe it has no way of knowing that its f_key is supposed to be A's id, and cannot thus set it. If you mapped A as an entity in B and use correct Cascade, Hibernate will retrieve A's ID when persisting and correctly set it in B.

Comment: Alternatively, you could place a @PrePersist annotated method in A looping through the B's and setting their fkey there, but in your case that would not be the "proper" action imo.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the code below:

```
    Class A {
      ...

      @JsonIgnore
      private Long id; @Id
      @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
      public Long getId()
      {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(Long id)
      {
          this.id = id;
      }

      @JsonView(View.Extended.class )
      List<B> b;

      @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinColumn(name="b_fkey")
      public List<B> getB(List<B> bList){
          return b;
      }      

      public void setB(List<B> bList){
          this.b = bList;
      }
```

The annotations over getters and setters give you better control over the hibernate columns.